# I just want to create fonts or scripts for a language other than English

Tags: fonts, scripting

I want to create font for a language called sanskrit which is cmpletely different from english. I want to know if there is any tool available for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools that can be used. Here are a few:

- [FontLab](https://www.fontlab.com/)
- [Fontographer](https://www.fontlab.com/font-editor/fontographer/)
- [Glyphs](https://glyphsapp.com/)
- [FontCreator](https://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator)

There are a few distinct aspects to creating a font for Devanagari script:

- You want to use Unicode encoding. But not all of the forms (shapes) needed are encoded in Unicode as characters. This means you will need more glyphs than encoded characters.
- When Devanagari text is rendered, the rendering engine will first map the Unicode characters to default glyphs. (You will determine which are the default glyphs in the font-development tool.) You'll need to understand how OpenType Layout works to perform substitutions in the glyph sequence based on contextual rules and OpenType "features" that the rendering engine will apply as it analyzes clusters. You will have to add "GSUB" OpenType Layout data in the font (using the tool) that provides the details about which glyph substitutions take place.
- After all of the substitutions have been processed, there may be positioning adjustments required. You'll use the tool to add "GPOS" OpenType Layout data for that.
- Of course, you need to create outlines for all the glyphs.

As an example of a substitution, if when a character sequence < U+0915 KA, U+094D VIRAMA> is followed by another consonant letter, a "half-KA" needs to be displayed. The rendering engine will apply a "half-form" feature to that sequence, and then the font needs to have substitution data that responds to that feature application by substituting the sequence of two default glyphs with the single glyph for half-ka.

As an example of positioning, a candrabindu appears above the preceding consonant letter, but the exact positioning of the glyph may need to be adjusted for different bases. The rendering engine will apply an "above marks" feature to the sequence, and then the font can have positioning data that responds to that feature application by making positioning adjustments.

It's not a trivial project, but it can be very interesting!